# Specific exception for wrong array length

Tags: .net, arrays, exception

I wrote a method, that takes an array with exact length as parameter.

When user try pass an array with wrong length to the method, the method generates an **ArgumentException**.

Is .NET have more specific type of exception for this case, or not? And what is the better practice: tell into the exception message the reason of the exception or the way to correct it?

Comment: No, it's the right exception for a wrong argument. Why you need to pass the length to the method at all? Maybe you can share the method with us.

Comment: Since arrays carry a length property inherently, what's the extra parameter *for*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever user can pass an array with any length. but if the length is not match to exact, the exception warns about it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ok, you're right, sorry. Removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is .NET have more specific type of exception for this case, or not?

No, the .Net framework does not have a more specific exception built in for your specific case.
And while you can always create your own custom exception class, I think that in most cases it's an overkill. I would say that an `ArgumentException` is the correct exception to throw in this situation.

> And what is the better practice: tell into the exception message the reason of the exception or the way to correct it?

When throwing an exception you include in the message what's causing the exception, not how to fix it.
In this particular case, I would probably write something like this in the error message:

```
"<ArrayParameterName> have and invalid length. Acceptable length is <x>"
```

Of course, change `<ArrayParameterName>` to the name of the argument and `<x>` to the accepted length.